# I need to process a list of already-tokenized sentences into skipgram samples. How do I do this efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a customized function to accomplish the business requirement I mentioned, but this one takes a very long time to run. I was wondering if there was any way to shorten that time?

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
assert os.path.isfile("train-v1.1.json"),"Non-existent file"
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
#import keras
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\W+')
#Reading the files.
def readFile(filename):
  with open(filename) as file:
    fields = []
    JSON = json.loads(file.read())
    articles = []
    for article in JSON["data"]:
      articleTitle = article["title"]
      article_body = []
      for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        paragraphContext = paragraph["context"]
        article_body.append(paragraphContext)
        for qas in paragraph["qas"]:
          question = qas["question"]
          answer = qas["answers"][0]
          fields.append({"question":question,"answer_text":answer["text"],"answer_start":answer["answer_start"],"paragraph_context":paragraphContext,"article_title":articleTitle})
      article_body = "\\n".join(article_body)
      article = {"title":articleTitle,"body":article_body}
      articles.append(article)
  fields = pd.DataFrame(fields)
  fields["question"] = fields["question"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["question"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["paragraph_context"] = fields["paragraph_context"].str.replace(regex," ")
  fields["answer_text"] = fields["answer_text"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["paragraph_context"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["article_title"] = fields["article_title"].str.replace("_"," ")
  assert not (fields["article_title"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  return fields,JSON["data"]
trainingData,training_JSON = readFile("train-v1.1.json")
print("JSON dataset read.")
#Text preprocessing
## Converting text to skipgrams
print("Tokenizing sentences.")
strings = trainingData.drop("answer_start",axis=1)
strings = strings.values.flatten()
textTokenizer = Tokenizer()
textTokenizer.fit_on_texts(strings)
questionsTokenized_train = pad_sequences(textTokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainingData["question"]))
print(questionsTokenized_train.shape)
contextTokenized_train = pad_sequences(textTokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainingData["paragraph_context"]))
print("Sentences tokenized.")
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams,make_sampling_table
def skipgrams_labels(sequence,vocabulary_length,window_size=3):
    try:
        couples,labels = skipgrams(sequence,vocabulary_length,window_size=window_size)
        assert len(couples) > 0
        target_word,context = zip(*couples)
        return np.array([target_word,context,labels]).T
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError("Exception in skipgrams_labels")
print("questionsTokenized shape" + str(questionsTokenized_train.shape))
# This is to train word2vec.
def word2vec_batch(sequences,vocabulary_length,batch_size=20):
    batch_indices = np.random.choice(sequences.shape[0], batch_size, replace=False)
    batch = sequences[batch_indices,:]
    assert batch.ndim == 2
    skipgrams_and_labels = [skipgrams_labels(sequence,vocabulary_length) for sequence in sequences]
    print("Maximum question length" + str(max([len(question) for question in batch])))
    shape_zero = len(skipgrams_and_labels)
    shape_one = max([len(x) for x in skipgrams_and_labels])
    shape_two = max([len(y) for x in skipgrams_and_labels for y in x])
    b = np.zeros((shape_zero,
    shape_one,
    shape_two))
    print(b.shape)
    for i in range(len(skipgrams_and_labels)):
        for j in range(len(skipgrams_and_labels[i])):
            for k in range(len(skipgrams_and_labels[i][j])):
                b[i][j][k] = skipgrams_and_labels[i][j][k]
    skipgrams_and_labels = b
    return skipgrams_and_labels
print("Test of skipgrams_labels")
questions_indices = np.random.randint(0,high=questionsTokenized_train.shape[0],size=1)
questions_sample = questionsTokenized_train[questions_indices,:]
vocabulary_length = len(textTokenizer.word_index) + 1
print("vocabulary length" + str(vocabulary_length))

i = skipgrams_labels(questions_sample[0],vocabulary_length)
print(i.shape)
print(i.dtype)

print("Test of word2vec_batch")
batch_tokens = word2vec_batch(questionsTokenized_train,vocabulary_length,batch_size=100)
print(batch_tokens.dtype)
for row in batch_tokens:
    print(row.shape)
```

According to my profiling tests, skipgrams_and_labels appears to be where the function spends most of its time. How can I improve this part of my code?

Comment: What exceptions are you trying to catch in `skipgrams_labels`? Is the `try... catch` necessary?

Comment: @Zchpyvr The try-catch blocks are not strictly necessary.

Comment: Can you add some description of your code in the question body. Change the title to represent your business requirement? 
Include `How can I make x faster` in the question body and not the title.

Comment: @bhathiya-perera: Change the title? Done.

Comment: @MontanaBurr looks like you misunderstood what I meant by business requirement. Ex: "Finding highest score" is a business requirement, & "How can I make my sorting and getting first element in an array faster" only highlights implementation and not the actual requirement.

Comment: @bhathiya-perera: Noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just some minor optimization, but it should already be faster.
Instead of looping over the length of `skipgrams_and_labels` and then do a triple index lookup with `skipgrams_and_labels[i][j][k]`, we loop directly over the elements and use enumerate to still get the index for b.

```
def word2vec_batch(sequences, vocabulary_length, batch_size=20):
    batch_indices = np.random.choice(sequences.shape[0], batch_size, replace=False)
    batch = sequences[batch_indices, :]
    assert batch.ndim == 2
    skipgrams_and_labels = [skipgrams_labels(sequence, vocabulary_length) for sequence in sequences]
    print(f"Maximum question length {max(len(question) for question in batch)}")
    shape_zero = len(skipgrams_and_labels)
    shape_one = max(len(x) for x in skipgrams_and_labels)
    shape_two = max(len(y) for x in skipgrams_and_labels for y in x)
    b = np.zeros((shape_zero, shape_one, shape_two))
    print(b.shape)
    for i, a in enumerate(skipgrams_and_labels):
        for j, b in enumerate(a):
            for k, c in enumerate(b):
                b[i][j][k] = c
    return b
```

EDIT:
This should be even faster because it gets rid of the other triple index lookup `b[i][j][k]`:

```
def word2vec_batch(sequences, vocabulary_length, batch_size=20):
    batch_indices = np.random.choice(sequences.shape[0], batch_size, replace=False)
    batch = sequences[batch_indices, :]
    assert batch.ndim == 2
    skipgrams_and_labels = [skipgrams_labels(sequence, vocabulary_length) for sequence in sequences]
    print(f"Maximum question length {max(len(question) for question in batch)}")
    shape_zero = len(skipgrams_and_labels)
    shape_one = max(len(x) for x in skipgrams_and_labels)
    shape_two = max(len(y) for x in skipgrams_and_labels for y in x)
    b = [c for a in skipgrams_and_labels for c in b for b in a]
    return np.array(b).reshape(shape_zero,shape_one,shape_two)
```